# Flutter - How do I create this Signup Form?

Tags: forms, flutter, authentication, dart, input

I'm trying to place an input form field underneath my text which says please enter your email. Could anyone assist? The thing I'm having the biggest problem with right now is I don't know how to add anything else below the text. Ideally, I'd like a centred input field. Code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your email'),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test Bench',
        home: Stack(children: [
          new Scaffold(
            body: new Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Hello, Let's Get Started...",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 60.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                      color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the text with a `Column` to append widgets underneath each other ([Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siFU8c_Heu0)). You can view more information [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout). This video also helps with general layouts ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjhE3rb5vtA)).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your email'),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test Bench',
      home: Stack(
        children: [
          Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Hello, Let's Get Started...",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 60.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    MyCustomForm(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have trouble to find how to add multiples widgets as the child of your Scaffold.

I suggest you to check out the [official documentation on layouts](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout)

You'll learn there how to create more complex layout and how you can add an input text field under a text widget.